# How do I log the name of the process that caused an outgoing internet connection attempt?

Tags: logging

If I enable UFW to block outgoing internet connections and set logging to "low," the log report that appears at /var/log only lists the PID of the application involved, not the application's name. The PID is useless information in a log because the PID does not live past a session. And when I view the log, I'm always looking at past sessions.

So how can I make the Log File record the name of the process that caused an outgoing internet connection attempt?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!